# About Transformer Equivalent Circuit

Tags: transformer

[image]

If I get the transformer equivalent circuit of the above circuit did I really get a purely resistive circuit with a resistance of n <sup>2</sup> times R<sub>Load</sub> . I am asking because I realized that in the oscilloscope screen there is delay(phase shift) between input voltage and input current. If I could not get purely resistive circuit why this equivalent circuit fails?

Comment: It’s only resistive for risetime of magnetic coupling time constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent circuit will only be \$(\frac{N1}{N2})^2R_{load}\$ if it was an ideal transformer.

Real trasformers have nonideal components. For example, the joule loss on the widings, or the core hysteresis. Those phenomena produce several effects, that must be accountable, in order to get the accurete equivalent circuit.

I sugest the reading Electric Machinery Fundamentals by Stephen Chapman, to better understand how to experimentally obtain your transformer's equivalent circuit.